# Quitar aviso de contenido desde codigo fuente

Tags: html, blogger

a veces wayback guarda blogs con aviso de contenido, y si le das a aceptar, wayback ya no muestra el blog, por eso me gustaría saber como quitar el aviso de contenido para adultos de blogger usando el código fuente y sin recargar la pagina, pongo un ejemplo:
https://web.archive.org/web/20170713031501/http://restgcaps.blogspot.com/
Si le doy a aceptar, wayback ya no muestra nada de información, es posible mostrar el contenido del blog usando el código fuente y/o inspeccionar?

Comment: No te sirve un clic derecho sobre el boton aceptar y copias le url del enlace, hasta que sea asi: `https://web.archive.org/web/20190224190641/http://restgcaps.blogspot.com/?interstitial=ABqL8_hG-_bDW7BRTzm7VZiDYMAf5qP2ljkO2Tkg5-Tk3N8IFjyRyl7h_-IzLB5O` ?

Comment: No, wayback me dice que no tiene la pagina guardada